# Multiple projects with common libraries

Tags: jar, dependencies

I want to split my Eclipse project into several modules. For simplicity's sake let's say those projects will be Client,Server and Common (which both Client and Server will depend on). There are several jars that would need to be used in all 3 projects.

Should I export the jars from the Common project or should each project define all of the external jars it depends on for itself?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) in such scenario....

Good Luck!!!

Comment: Yes I was thinking about it, but integrating Maven takes some time and expertise - it will probably come at a later stage but for now I just want to make the project more modular without investing too much time and effort.